# errors while validating whitelabel in sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid

We are getting Error while validating whitelabel listing in sendgrid

> • Expected CNAME for "info.domainname.org" to match "u6790682.wl183.sendgrid.net".
>   • Expected CNAME for "s1._domainkey.domain.org" to match "s1.domainkey.u6790682.wl183.sendgrid.net".
>   • Expected CNAME for "s2._domainkey.domain.org" to match "s2.domainkey.u6790682.wl183.sendgrid.net".

Answer (score 27):

I faced this problem recently until I discovered the problem.
First, I suggest you read here for an introduction to resolving your problem: [Sendgrid Troubleshooter (Former link is dead. Updated with an archive.)](http://web.archive.org/web/20170706082258/https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Troubleshooting/Authentication/i_have_created_dns_records_but_the_whitelabel_wizard_is_not_validating_them.html)

For my case, the problem was: 
**TLD Auto-Appending** which is done automatically by Azure.

I quote, "Some DNS hosts will automatically add your top-level domain to the end of DNS records you create, which can turn a CNAME for “email.domain.com” into “email.domain.com.domain.com”."

Be sure to follow the convention on existing records in your DNS panel when adding new ones, as sometimes you will only need to add what is to the left of the top-level domain.

i.e. A CNAME for “email.” becomes “email.domain.com”

Do try to verify the Cname data on your hosting provider and compare with s1._domainkey.domain.org

Comment: Exactly my problem on Godaddy. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue using Azure and GoDaddy. Your solution works great! Thanks!

Comment: The solution link looks out to be dead.

Comment: @UtkarshSharma , I have updated the link. A lot has changed about SendGrid since the company merged with another.

Comment: I had the same issue with Namecheap. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on CloudFlare. Disable proxy and wait for 1-2 min then verify again.